# Pandas create rows based on interval between to dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to expand a dataframe containing a number of columns by creating rows based on the interval between two date columns.

For this I am currently using a method that basically creates a cartesian product, which works well on small datasets, but is not good in large sets because it is very inefficient.

This method will be used on a ~ 2-million row by 50 column Dataframe spanning multiple years from min to max date. The resulting dataset will be about 3 million rows, so a more effective approach is required.

I have not succeeded in finding an alternative method which is less resource intensive.
What would be the best approach for this?

**My current method here:**

```py
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd

raw_data = {'id': ['aa0', 'aa1', 'aa2', 'aa3'],
'number': [1, 2, 2, 1],
'color': ['blue', 'red', 'yellow', "green"],
'date_start': [date(2022,1,1), date(2022,1,1), date(2022,1,7), date(2022,1,12)],
'date_end': [date(2022,1,2), date(2022,1,4), date(2022,1,9), date(2022,1,14)]}


df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
```

This gives the following result
[image: DataFrame]

Now to create a set containing all possible dates between the min and max date of the set:

```py
df_d = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range(df['date_start'].min(), df['date_end'].max() + pd.Timedelta('1d'), freq='1d')})
```

This results in an expected frame containing all the possible dates

[image: DataFrame]

Finally to cross merge the original set with the date set and filter resulting rows based on start and end date per row

```py
df_total = pd.merge(df, df_d,how='cross')
df = df_total[(df_total['date_start']<df_total['date']) & (df_total['date_end']>=df_total['date']) ]
```

This leads to the following final
[image: DataFrame]

This final dataframe is exactly what is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Efficient Solution

```
d = df['date_end'].sub(df['date_start']).dt.days
df1 = df.reindex(df.index.repeat(d))
i = df1.groupby(level=0).cumcount() + 1

df1['date'] = df1['date_start'] + pd.to_timedelta(i, unit='d')
```

### How it works?

Subtract start from end to calculate the number of days elapsed, then  `reindex` the dataframe by repeating the index exactly elapsed number of days times. Now group `df1` by `index` and use `cumcount` to create a sequential counter then create a `timedelta` series using this counter and add this with `date_start` to get the result

**Result**

```
    id  number   color  date_start    date_end        date
0  aa0       1    blue  2022-01-01  2022-01-02  2022-01-02
1  aa1       2     red  2022-01-01  2022-01-04  2022-01-02
1  aa1       2     red  2022-01-01  2022-01-04  2022-01-03
1  aa1       2     red  2022-01-01  2022-01-04  2022-01-04
2  aa2       2  yellow  2022-01-07  2022-01-09  2022-01-08
2  aa2       2  yellow  2022-01-07  2022-01-09  2022-01-09
3  aa3       1   green  2022-01-12  2022-01-14  2022-01-13
3  aa3       1   green  2022-01-12  2022-01-14  2022-01-14
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is an approvement, here the `pd.date_range` only gets created for each start and end date in each row. the created list gets exploded and joined to the original `df`

```
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd

raw_data = {'id': ['aa0', 'aa1', 'aa2', 'aa3'],
'number': [1, 2, 2, 1],
'color': ['blue', 'red', 'yellow', "green"],
'date_start': [date(2022,1,1), date(2022,1,1), date(2022,1,7), date(2022,1,12)],
'date_end': [date(2022,1,2), date(2022,1,4), date(2022,1,9), date(2022,1,14)]}


df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)

s = df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x['date_start'], x['date_end'], freq='1d',inclusive='right').date,axis=1).explode()
df.join(s.rename('date'))
```